# MySQL server not started after installed Apache Cassandra

Tags: mysql, cassandra

I am trying to work with multiple database with single project. I have successfully integrated my project with MySQL database, but after installing Cassandra (by DataStax 3.9.0) I face problem to connect with MySQL database.

I got error

> `can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)`

I have reverted the process and uninstalled Cassandra but there are same issue at time of starting MySQL. Also in the Services TAB in Control Panel, I do not get any option to start MYSQL Service Manually and the Startup type is "Automatic".

Answer (score 0):

Please check if mysql database is already running or not.If running you can stop start with the database you want to work.

Comment: the OP has already stated that she's having trouble starting MySQL, so this answer is not constructive.